# AJAX call show [object Object] (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have AJAX cal to back end

Here is code on front-end:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Profile_Data", "Interwier")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
            var question2 = data;
            for (var i = 0; i <= question2.length - 1; i++) {
                var videoHTML = '<div style="width:100%;overflow-y: scroll;background:white;height:60%;border-bottom:solid;border-color: #A9A9A9;">' + '<div style="float:left; width:50%;height:296px;border-right:solid;border-color: #A9A9A9;margin-bottom:10px;">' +
                    '<video  style="width:100%;height:290px; object-fit: contain;padding-right: 15px;padding-left:15px;" controls>';
                videoHTML += '<source src="' + document.location.origin + "/uploads/" + question2[i].Linkes + ".webm" + '" type="video/webm">';
                videoHTML += '</video>' + '</div>' + '<div style="float:right;width:48%;text-align:center;height:296px;padding-top:30px;">' + '<div style="font-size:20px">' + '<b>' + question2[i].FIO + '</b>' + '</div>' + '<div style="font-size:20px">' + '<b>' + question2[i].City + '</b>' + '</div>' + '<div style="font-size:20px">' + '<b>' + (yyyy - question2[i].Vozrast) + '</b>' + '</div>' + '<div class="qustion-div-two" style="height:160px;margin-top:20px; background:white;" >' +
                    '<div id="comments" style="width: 100%; height: 70%;">' + '</div>' +
                    '<div id="write_field" style="width:100%;height:30%;font-size:15px;">' +
                    '<input type="text" "style="width:99%; height:75%;margin-left:2px;margin-bottom:5px;" />' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>';
                $(".videolist").append(videoHTML);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And here is code on back-end:

```
 public ActionResult Profile_Data()
    {
        var dataforprofile = TempData["FIO"];
        var profiledata = db.Link
            .Where(x => x.Interwier.FIO == dataforprofile)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ID = x.Link_Id,
                Linkes = x.Link1,
                FIO = x.Interwier.FIO,
                City = x.Interwier.City,
                English_level = x.Interwier.English,
                Vozrast = x.Interwier.Birthday
            })
            .ToList();
        return Json(profiledata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Script is working but  I get this when call alert

[image]

Where is my problem?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Use `console.log` instead `alert` for objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually JSON object, you will need to convert it to string for viewing string version in the alert which would be done using `JSON.stringify()` or you can `console.log(data)` to see the Json returned.

Try the following:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

or see in console by logging it :

```
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

alert(data); data is collection of list, if you want to see object data value then you need to loop over the data

```
if(data!=null) {
$.each(data, function (i, data) {
           console.log(data)
        });
  }
```

contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

```
data type is json then you need to send data to server to be json format in your case should be empty data:{}
```